# Anonymous Authentication in IIS 7

Tags: iis-7

When I disable Anonymous Authentication in IIS 7 then it does not allow me to download public content from client browser as well as from web application by passing URL.
But I want to disable end user to download public content from client browser but they can download public content through web application by passing URL. i.e.  https://xxx.com/data/MyDownload.doc.

Is there any one whose have any idea regarding same?

Comment: you can find the answer here .
hope it helps . http://forums.iis.net/